# use a while true loop while the code below is still running (python)

Tags: python, while-loop

Im making this game called:

IDLE PEN ,(MAKE PENS)

and every 1 second i get a bonus pen

how i get a bonus pen is doing this

```
Import time
While true
    make a pen()
    time.sleep(1)
```

but i have some code under the while true loop.
the code  under the while true loop is like buttons to
upgrade the pens or make a pen
So how do i make the code under the while true loop work?

This is my game im happy for anyone to copy it
its not ready yet

```
import functools
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import time
from random import seed
from random import randint

# eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee





window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title('Idle Pen')


def print_pen(number: int):
    return f"Pens: {number}"


class pencount:

    def __init__(self):
        self.pencount = 0
        self.text = tkinter.Text(height=1, width=30)
        self.text.insert("1.0", print_pen(0))
        self.text['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.text.pack()

    def changepencount(self, count):
        if self.pencount + count < 0:
            return
        self.pencount = self.pencount + count
        self.text['state'] = 'normal'
        self.text.delete("1.0", "end")
        self.text.insert("1.0", print_pen(self.pencount))
        self.text['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.text.pack()
        

pen = pencount()

changepenup = functools.partial(pen.changepencount, 1)
B = tkinter.Button(window, text="Make Pen", command=changepenup)


changependown = functools.partial(pen.changepencount, -100) 

A = tkinter.Button(window, text='Penmaker', command=changependown)

Q = tkinter.Button(window, text="Quit", command=window.destroy)

U = tkinter.Button


# eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

B.pack()
A.pack()
Q.pack()
    

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: maybe you should run `while True` in separated `thread` Or maybe you should use `root.after(milliseconds, function)` to run code periodically (instead of using `while True`)` There are examples how to use `after()` to periodically update time on widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `threading` to run your loop in separated thread and then main thread may run `tkitner`

OR you can use `tkinter` function `after()` (instead of `while True`) to run function with delay and this function should use again `after()` to run itself.

```
import tkinter as tk
        
# --- functions ---

def update():
    global value

    value += 1
    
    text = f'make penny: {value}'
    print(text)
    label['text'] = text

    # run again after 1s (1000ms)
    root.after(1000, update)

# --- main ---

value = 0

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="make penny: 0")
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
button.pack()

# run first time after 1s (1000ms)
root.after(1000, update)

root.mainloop()
```